# Are there any options other than using #define for conditional compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I want to use conditional compilation for testing different properties of my code; however, I don't want to pollute the global namespace. Would someone be kind enough to let me know if there is a way to use conditional compilation without using `#define`?

I have searched for an option, but most of the other posts refer to the usage of `static const`, etc to choose different code during run-time. I, however, want to compile a different code. For example, instead of:

```cpp
#define A_HASH_DEFINE
...
#ifdef A_HASH_DEFINE
 Some code
#elif ANOTHER_HASH_DEFINE
 Some other code
#endif
```

I would like to be able to use something with a scope, such as:

```cpp
scope::A_SCOPED_HASH_DEFINE
...
#ifdef scope::A_SCOPED_HASH_DEFINE
 Some code
#elif scope::ANOTHER_SCOPED_HASH_DEFINE
 Some other code
#endif
```

Comment: The preprocessor is dumb as a post in this regard. No scopes, nothing but longer names, eg: `SCOPE_A_SCOPED_HASH_DEFINE`

Comment: by scope do you mean name space?
use the `constexpr` inside the namespce 
`constexpr uint64_t HASH_DEFINE = 256;`

Comment: @user4581301 I see. I guess that is what I will have to do :/ Thanks!

Comment: @ajax_velu Yes, I mean inside a namespace. Does constexpr work with #ifdef preprocessor commands?

Comment: If you are looking at a lot of very different or very complicated code, consider placing the different code in separate files and letting the build system deal with it by linking in the correct file.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the advice! I will think about which one is the best option for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using C++17, you should use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

It is essentially an `if` statement where the branch is chosen at compile-time, and any not-taken branches are discarded. It is cleaner than having the `#ifdef`s splattered throughout your code.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
constexpr bool debug_mode = true;
#else
constexpr bool debug_mode = false;
#endif

if constexpr (debug_mode) {
   //debug code
}
```

You can read more about how it replaces `#if … #else` in FooNathan's blog:

[The year is 2017 - Is the preprocessor still needed in C++?](https://foonathan.net/blog/2017/05/08/preprocessor.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am going to read the article when I get back home. I believe, this solves the problem for most of my projects. Would it be possible to use it for C++ 11 and above instead of just C++17 and above?

Comment: @AnilCelikMaral tbh, most compilers these days are able to remove code based on a constant expression, so the constexpr here is just a hint to the compiler for something it can already figure out. See this dumb example here: https://godbolt.org/z/4WIq_2  
The code for the method is entirely removed if the option is const. Changing it to true, will prompt the compiler to generate the code.

Comment: @robthebloke No, it's more than that. The code inside a `constexpr` branch not taken can be "invalid", which is not true if you're just relying on optimisations. Two different beasts.

Comment: i assume the `constexpr` here remains global if defined in a global scope in header files

Answer (score 1):

When using preprocessor definitions we always have to deal with the tradeoff that we are polluting the "global namespace".

It's not really the global namespace, of course, but it's own namespace: trouble is, these macro names actually take effect in *every* scope, due to their nature.

We simply accept this.

---

We try to limit them by perhaps keeping them to individual translation units. Or, if they need to be in a header, we switch to `const bool`s instead.

If you need conditional compilation in the truest sense and you can spell this in non-preprocessor C++ using `if constexpr`, then so much the better.

Otherwise it's just something we have to deal with. We at least try to use descriptive names and avoid using common terms that may conflict with third-party headers. If/when they do, we change them.

---

If you're still finding that your macros are *too* polluting, then it could be that your switching logic encapsulates too much code. In such a case, you may consider moving the logic into your build system and changing which source files you build in the first place.

For example, an OpenGL renderer implementation versus a DirectX renderer implementation (an example that only works if you switch between these at build time, as you would be with a macro!).

Comment: I think I will look into constexpr more. For now, I will let the Makefile deal with building different versions depending on which one I want. Thanks a lot for the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with conditional compilation it is very common to omit declaring the define at compile time, a nice trick to make it more type-safe is to use an enumeration (a boolean value may also work) to ensure a valid value is defined at compile time.

Example

```
enum class SystemEnum { MAC, LINUX, WINDOWS };
const SystemEnum mySystem = SystemEnum::MY_SYSTEM;

void func() {

#if MY_SYSTEM == MAC
    doMacStuff();
#elif MY_SYSTEM == LINUX
    doLinuxStuff();
#elif MY_SYSTEM == WINDOWS
    doWindowsStuff();
#else
#error "You must define MY_SYSTEM to compile this"
#endif

    if constexpr (mySystem == SystemEnum::MAC)
        doMacStuff();
    else if constexpr (mySystem == SystemEnum::LINUX)
        doLinuxStuff();
    else if constexpr (mySystem == SystemEnum::WINDOWS)
        doWindowsStuff();
    else
        doError();
}
```